# Body background image goes behind sections background color

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I have a problem with my background body image. When I put a color on my different sections, the background image disapear I suppose behind the color and I don't know why.

If I put a background-color on the body it works but I want a different color on each section of my page.

Here is the wireframe : [Wireframe][1] And for now I have this : [Project][2]

Here is a part of the code.

```js
function myFunction(tag) {
  $("#cssmenu a.active").removeClass("active"); //remove previous li active class
  $(tag).closest("a").addClass("active");
}
```

```css
    html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0; 
}
body {
  background-image: url("https://montaigne-energie.fr/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/phare_blan3.svg");
  background-position: 50% 2%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 140% auto;
  background-attachment: local;
}

#home {
  background-color: rgba(182, 166, 128, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
}

#services {
  background-color: rgb(33, 59, 82,.8);
  height: 100%;
}

#valeurs {
background-color: rgba(182, 166, 128, 0.8);
height: 100%;

}

#missions {
  background-color: rgb(33, 59, 82,.8);
  height: 100%;
}

#section5 {
  background-color: rgba(182, 166, 128, 0.8);
  height: 100%;
}

#footer {
  background-color: rgb(33, 59, 82,.8);
  height: 100%;
}

.section{
min-height: 100%;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 35%;
  right: 2%;
  bottom: auto;
  z-index: 10;
}

.lader ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.lader li {
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.lader span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.circle {
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  left: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-color: none;
}

.lader a.active span {
  background-color: white;
}

nav a:hover span {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="home">
 

<nav class="lader" id="cssmenu">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="#home" class="active" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="circle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#services" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="circle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#valeurs" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="circle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#missions" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="circle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#section5" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="circle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#footer" onclick="myFunction(this)">
            <span class="circle"></span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
<div class="section" id="services"></div>
<div class="section" id="valeurs"></div>
<div class="section" id="missions"></div>
<div class="section" id="sections5"></div>
<div class="section" id="footer"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, where exactly do you want your image to come...if possible can you share the screenshot of the wireframe or something like that

Comment: _"and I don't know why"_ - because you can't see through a solid color ...?

Comment: Hey 
Can I put the background image on top of the solid color then ?

Comment: @Hypermystic Here is the wireframe : https://xd.adobe.com/view/b04dbb17-5fd9-426d-a02b-6eb9c99bb2e3-e51e/screen/5f938c4d-2f84-467c-8bdb-c0a41f1cc13f?fullscreen

And for now I have this : https://montaigne-energie.fr/home/

Answer (score 1):

Try someting like `background-color: rgba(21, 45, 52, 0.3)`.Replace all your background color into this.

This will make your div background color has an alpha, so may be you can see the background image from the body element.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks 
It doesn't work either 

https://montaigne-energie.fr/home/

Comment: I checked the site. Your body have a background-color.
Add someting like `background-color: rgba(21, 45, 52, 0.3)` on your body element too.I tested, it works.

Comment: Thanks
It works but the 0.3 opacity make the color transparent...

Comment: If you want the color is not transparent and let the image show, you should make sure the background image z-index is bigger than background color.May be create a cover just above you all elements, and set the background image.

Answer (score 0):

You can't see the color because there isn't any content in your div. You can add something to your div or just add the code below to your CSS

```
div{
    min-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Hi ! thanks

I didn't put all the code but there is content inside the divs